# Error : case class implementing parent's abstract method

Tags: scala

I am learning scala, so bear with me if this a stupid question. I am experimenting with case classes and trying out the following:-

```
case class A {
    def eval(x: Int): Boolean
}

case class B extends A

case class C extends A {
    override def eval(x: Int): Boolean = true
    // Compiler error is - 
    // Multiple markers at this line
    // - Missing closing brace `}' assumed here
    // - expected start of definition
}
```

Is it not possible for case classes to implement abstract methods?

Comment: Yes, it is most certainly possible for a `case class` to implement an abstract member from a base type.

Answer (score 3):

A case class cannot inherit another case class (the compiler does a lot of magic). In scala, you would typically use a trait, so your code would look like:

```
trait A {
  def eval(x: Int): Boolean
}

case class C() extends A {
  override def eval(x: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`abstract` `case` `class` is a contradiction in terms. It is not advisable to extend from a `case class` and by making a `case class` abstract you are forced to sub-class it to have an instantiable class.

The common pattern is an `abstract class` or `trait` as the base with one or more (often more than one) `case class`es *always at the leafs of the inheritance tree*.

Comment: Even if I make class A a non-case class, it still does not compile

Comment: Ajay - if you make A both abstract and not a case class, this should compile fine (although with a warning, since you've created a case class with no arguments, which functionality is deprecated).